# working with '#!' in a ajax function url

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, escaping, character

ok I have created the below ajax request and I am having trouble passing the '#!' characters to the browser from the response created by the function. When I view the console in the web browser the '#!' characters are completely removed from the url. Is it possible to keep these characters in the url?

Code:

```
$(function() {
function loadStats() {

  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://stats.nba.com/players/gamelogs/'+decodeURIComponent('#!')+'?&callback=?',
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonReturnData',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
      CF: 'PLAYER_NAME*E*James Harden',
      Season: '2016-17',
      SeasonType: 'Regular Season',
      format: 'json'
    },

    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);

    } //success

  }); //AJAX Call
} //load Chart

loadStats();

});
```

Comment: change decodeURIComponent with encodeURIComponent

Answer (score 0):

This is because url fragments (denoted by everything following the `#` sign) are *client-side only*. Fragments do not get sent with XHR/ajax. According to the spec, XHR specifically [excludes the url fragment from the response url](https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/#the-responseurl-attribute). In your specific case you are using `decodeURIComponent` which is preserving the `#` sign, causing it to be stripped.

Fragments are only evaluated client-side after the requested resource is returned from the server.

You may be able to circumvent this by using [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent).

---

More info can be found on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) regarding url fragments.

MDN also has documentation on [`window.location.hash`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)

Comment: Yeah I figured that, and I am stuck. Thanks for the comments though.

Comment: @user7104290 `encodeURIComponent` should do the trick. But I suspect there's something else wrong with the code. Why do you need the `#!` in the URL? Is it supported as an endpoint in the NBA API you're using?